# How to make IDEs aware of addition to classes by @annotations and AST transformations?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, groovy, annotations

I am creating a custom annotation with a local Groovy AST transformation, that target types, and will add a few extra methods and a field to the classes it annotates (much like the [@Bindable annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/beans/Bindable.html)).

But how can I make an IDE aware of the extra fields and methods added to the class?

I see that IntelliJ is aware of the extra methods the @Bindable annotation adds, but it doesn't seem to work with mine.

Comment: This normally works fine in Eclipse if you have the Groovy support working; Eclipse will inspect the `.class` files to find things like fields, and it even works in same-class autocomplete in my experience.

Comment: @chrylis ok. I am not able to get it working with IntelliJ 2017.3. Is there something explicit I need to do in my annotation / transformation or in IntelliJ to make IntelliJ inspect the .class files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IntelliJ you either need to write an extension or use GDSL. Some Annotations are supported out of the box, but those are all special cases in the Groovy support, i.e. there is no code that infers added Methods or Fields generically. From your description GDSL should be enough.

The [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) for GDSL is somewhat thin.

TO THE NEW has a [series of articles](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/gdsl-awesomeness-introduction-to-gdsl-in-intellij-idea/) about GDSL that I read a while ago. I remember them to be slightly outdated but a good starting point.

Spock uses a gdsl file that may serve as a good reference: [spock.gdsl](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/resources/org/spockframework/idea/spock.gdsl)

A tip if you decide to try GDSL: open IntelliJ from a terminal. You can use `println` in the GDSL file for debugging.

I guess it's possible to clone the IntelliJ repository and test your GDSL in an IntelliJ that's running in a debugger (from another IntelliJ instance), but I haven't tried that.

At the end of the Jetbrains documentation you'll find some linked examples. One of them is for `@Bindable` so that might be *almost* what you're looking for.

```
contributor(context()) {
  if (classType?.fields?.find {it.hasAnnotation("groovy.beans.Bindable")}) {
    method name: "addPropertyChangeListener", type: "void", params: [s: "java.lang.String", l: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener"]
    method name: "addPropertyChangeListener", type: "void", params: [l: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener"]

    method name: "removePropertyChangeListener", type: "void", params: [s: "java.lang.String", l: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener"]
    method name: "removePropertyChangeListener", type: "void", params: [l: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener"]

    method name: "firePropertyChange", type: "void", params: [s: "java.lang.String", o1: "java.lang.Object", o2: "java.lang.Object"]

    method name: "getPropertyChangeListeners", type: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener[]"
    method name: "getPropertyChangeListeners", type: "java.beans.PropertyChangeListener[]", params: [s: "java.lang.String"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get autocomplete working. However, IntelliJ still indicates that the methods are are unknown/dynamic (underlining their name) or indicates that there is an error if @CompileStatic is used (showing the method names in red). Even if I use the content from the bindableTransform.gdsl verbatim. Makes me think IntelliJ has some extra secret sauce I am missing.

Comment: I currently have IntelliJ 2017.3 and cannot reproduce this. For me, once I get auto-complete, the rest also works. Depending on the implementation `@CompileStatic` may require a type checking extension, but that's not IDE specific (if I understand correctly, it compiles?)

Comment: You are right. It does seem to work. I just needed to be a little patient... it looks like it can about 10-30 seconds for IntelliJ to start making use of the changes... it also seems to be a little hit-and-miss at times. Is there a rule for where the .gdsl file should be located for it to work consistently?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, IntelliJ has a non-obvious way to apply GDSL (modifications). What makes it usually deterministic: go to the GDSL file and add a line (i.e. press enter) and then ctrl+s. At the top of the editor a yellow box will appear and you need to "Activate back" (link in said box) the GDSL.